# XCUITest waits for apps that are not tested to reach idle state

Tags: swift, xcuitest, monkey

1. During the execution of my use case, I clicked to jump to a third-party APP, such as AppStore or browser
2. Then XCUITest has been waiting for the third-party APP to reach the idle state
3. The test fails because it cannot find the test target program

Why does the test program keep waiting for the third-party APP to reach the idle state, and how to solve it?

The solution I tried: Before each click in the test case, the status of the target APP will be checked, and if it is not in the foreground, it will be pulled back to the foreground.
But this method was not executed in the second step above.

The execution log is as follows:

````
   t =  1871.85s Tap Application 'test app'[0.00, 0.00] -> (297.1, 160.2)
   t =  1871.85s     Wait for test app to idle
   t =  1872.03s     Find the Application 'test app'
   t =  1872.09s     Check for interrupting elements affecting "test app" Application
   t =  1872.18s         **Wait for com.apple.mobilesafari to idle**
   t =  1872.34s         **Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle**
   t =  1932.47s         Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 58
   t =  1932.57s         Find: Descendants matching predicate identifier == "NotificationShortLookView" OR elementType == 7
   t =  1933.59s     Retrying `Tap Application 'test app'[0.00, 0.00] -> (297.1, 160.2)` (attempt #2)
   t =  1933.59s         Wait for test app to idle
   t =  1933.76s         Find the Application 'test app'
   t =  1964.77s             Find the Application 'test app' (retry 1)
   t =  1995.79s             Find the Application 'test app' (retry 2)
   t =  2025.80s             Collecting extra data to assist test failure triage
   t =  2025.81s                 Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 1899
   t =  2025.82s                 Requesting snapshot of accessibility
hierarchy for app with pid 1899
/Users/zoro/Documents/workspace/zoro_swiftmonkey/zoro_swiftmonkeyUITests/zoro_swiftmonkeyUITests.swift:61: error: -[zoro_swiftmonkeyUITests.zoro_swiftmonkeyUITests testMonkey] : Failed to get matching snapshot: Timed out while evaluating UI query.
   t =  2030.37s Tear Down
Test Case '-[zoro_swiftmonkeyUITests.zoro_swiftmonkeyUITests testMonkey]' failed (2030.643 seconds).
Test Suite 'zoro_swiftmonkeyUITests' failed at 2021-03-05 11:25:32.133.
    Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 2030.643 (2030.643) seconds
Test Suite 'zoro_swiftmonkeyUITests.xctest' failed at 2021-03-05 11:25:32.133.
    Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 2030.643 (2030.644) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' failed at 2021-03-05 11:25:32.134.
    Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 2030.643 (2030.645) seconds```
````

Comment: Can you share your code? It's difficult to trace what you're trying to do and where things are going awry from the log and description.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this question answer list（the second answer）[1]: [Disabling waiting for idle state in UI testing of iOS apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277026/disabling-waiting-for-idle-state-in-ui-testing-of-ios-apps)