# iOS UnitTests with preloaded sqlite3 DB

Tags: ios, unit-testing, command-line, sqlite

I am required to create iOS unit tests, where i need to push an sql .db into app location/sandbox/whatever (may be from testsuit's setUp() func) and run some CRUD operations from the testcases and later delete the db from tearDown() when tests done. How can i push a .db into app location for test, which will be used just like a db used inside app.

Another question, I need to run automated tests, so is there any command (like in Android we use adb, in Tize we use gdb) for iOS app to insert these database file in app location to run those testcases. If i am missing any point please help.

What is the standard way to test CRUD operations in a simulated db for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my study, there is no adb/sdb like tool for iOS. Moreover there is an workaround for performing test on real database.

### Steps

1. Keep the test-database into App/resource folder. You can skip this large test-database from your release build by following [these technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42800079/1084174).
2. Make a function in App side to replaceWithTestDatabase(), which basically replace your App database with App/resource/test-database. You can temporary copy current App db if you need.
3. If you want to access from AppTests (unit test), you can simply call Aapp/replaceWithTestDatabase as iOS Tests are hosted under main App.
4. If you want to access from AppUITests, you need to send extra launch argument from setUp() method to let App know that it should call replaceWithTestDatabase from app delegates. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33466038/1084174) is a nice explanation how we can  send arguments to main App from AppUITests.

Hope it helps.